# I have a file in Unix with data set as below, i want to generate more data like this but no duplicates. Looking for a unix shell code. Below is sample

Tags: shell, unix

I want to generate more data based on some sample data i already have in a file stored in Unix location.
looking for a unix shell code.

```
ID,FN,LN,Gender
1,John,hopkins,M
2,Andrew,Singh,M
3,Ram,Lakshman,M
4,ABC,DEF,F
5,Virendra,Sehwag,F
6,Sachin,Tendulkar,F
```

Comment: Create a file with all permutations from AA to ZZ, shuffle the file for the second and third column and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `awk` to read the existing data into an array and then keep printing it over and over with new IDs:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v n=100 '
  BEGIN {
    l = 0;
  }
  /^[0-9]/ {
    a[l] = $2","$3","$4;
    l++;
  }
  { print }
  END {
    for ( i = l; i <= n; i++ ) {
      printf "%d,%s\n", i, a[i%l];
    }
  }
'
```

`n` is the number of IDs you want (existing IDs + generated).